# Is Details Activity pattern in Android the solution to also handle User Input?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So I was reading the book for android development called Head First Android Development among others the authors suggest the pattern of the details activities. This suggest that when you want for example to present a set of pizzas to your user you create a RecyclerView presenting all the available pizzas and when a user click on one you then start the a details activity presenting all the details for the particular pizza using the intent to pass the particular pizza id.

This feels really elegant but what if I want the user to have a list of pizzas and be able to insert new pizzas for them selves which will be then presented in the same `RecyclerView`, my idea at the moment is that I Should start another details activity getting the input from the user and then passing all details(ingredients) of the user input to the presentation activity using again the intent. This solution works fine but it just feels too sloppy. Can you suggest another solution that does not demand passing around huge amounts of data using intents ?

Comment: That design from the book is not final everything can be changed. For this case you can create a Button in the Activity with RecyclerView and If the use clicks, he add an item and you update the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I should tell you.

Passing some strings(ingredients) is not really a 'huge amounts of data'.

Even if you send data through intents to your other activity, it will not be stored anywhere and will only be available temporarily. As soon as your activity gets destroyed you'll lose that data.

Better approach is to launch your detail activity, ask for new entry to your pizza list, store it in a persistent storage and finish detail activity instead of starting the presentation activity again.

Android keeps stack of activities so when detail activity finishes, your presentation activity will be restored. Read the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) of an activity and see all the methods that will be called.

One of the method which will be called is `onResume` where you should refresh your `recyclerView` by getting the latest data from the [persistent storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).